# How to create a column and fill in data based on criteria on current fields

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need your kind help on SQL code realizing the function described below.

I have a table named "Base" with 3 columns. I need to add a new column. In the new column named "New Result", it will check each ID number 1st. If the same ID appeared twice in the table (measured by conditions A and B, as shown as ID 100 and 101), then fill in value as measured by condition B in the "New Result" field. If an ID showed up only once (measured only by conditions A or B, as shown as ID 103 and 104), then copy original value over to the new column.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`FIRST_VALUE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html) window function.

```
select t.*,
first_value(result) over(partition by id order by conditions desc) as new_result
from tbl t
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked.   with Redshift it required me to add the following statement after  "order by conditions desc"
"rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following"